# I can't interpolate my hash because apparently it is nil class? Could anyone shed some light on this?

Tags: ruby, hash, iterator, iteration, string-interpolation

Is there an alternative to iteration or a condition I can make that will allow me to interpolate the values of just one hash? I've inspected the results of my input and apparently the array that i'm saving my hashes into disappears when there is only one hash. I've also tested the results and they're of Nil class.

```
def print_with_index(students)

   students.each_with_index do |student, index|
      index_plus_one = index + 1  
   puts "#{index_plus_one}. #{students[:name]} (#{students[:cohort]} cohort)"

end
end
```

How do i solve my problem and also why do hashes behave this way?

Full code:

```
def print_header
  puts "The students of Villains Academy"
  puts "--------------"
end

def print_footer(names)
  puts "Overall, we have #{names.count} great students"
end

def input_students
  puts "Please enter the names and then the cohort of the students"
  puts "To finish, just hit return twice"
    #created an empty array
  students = []
    #getting the first name
  name = gets.chomp
  cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym
   if cohort.empty?
    cohort = :november
   end

  if cohort !~ /january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december/
  puts "Please enter a valid month"
  puts "Warning months are case sensitive. Please enter in lowercase characters."
    cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym
  end

  while !name.empty? do
     # add the student hash to the array called students
  students << {name: name, cohort: cohort}
    if students.count > 1
       puts "Now we have #{students.count} students"
    else students.count == 1
       puts "Now we have #{students.count} student"
    end
       #getting another name from the user
    name = gets.chomp
    cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym

    if cohort.empty?
     cohort = :november
    end

    if cohort !~ /january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december/
    puts "Please enter a valid month"
    puts "Warning months are case sensitive. Please enter in lowercase characters."
    cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym
  end

 end

 bycohort = students.sort_by { |v| v[:cohort] }
  filter = students.select! { |student| student[:cohort] == :november }
 puts bycohort #This allows me to see all of my hashes before they are filtered
 puts ""

 bycohort
 filter
 end

def print_with_index(students)

students.each_with_index do |students, index|
  index_plus_one = index + 1 
  puts "#{index_plus_one}. #{students[:name]} (#{students[:cohort]} cohort)"

   end
  end

### body ###
students = input_students
print_header
print_with_index(students)
print_footer(students)
```

Comment: The first argument to the `each_with_index` block should be `student` (singular) to avoid confusion. Also, the stuff inside `#{...}` in string interpolation is any Ruby expression so `"#{index + 1}. #{student[:name]}..."` is fine.

Comment: I'm still getting NilClass errors for my code when I try to call the print_with_index method. Even if I make Sean's changes and change the scope of my name and cohort variables and print explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me though, i think with `each_with_index` enum, you have to pass in an array of hashes i.e. [{...}, {...}, {...}], not a single hash with multiple keys-values

```
def print_with_index(students)

  students.each_with_index do |students, index|
      index_plus_one = index + 1  
      puts "#{index_plus_one}. #{students[:name]} (#{students[:cohort]} cohort)"
  end
end

print_with_index([{name:"b", cohort: "c"}]) 
# 1. b (c cohort)
```

Comment: Ahh ok. But what if I don't know what the value of each of them will be? The user will be inputting the hash values.

Comment: what do you mean by not knowing the value of user input? i think it's ok as long as the key matches (i..e `name` & `cohort`) your interpolation `...[:name]` & `...[:cohort]`, and the inputs are being stored as hashes in array

Comment: Ahh it's ok I forgot about scope for a few minutes there. I can just add a few @s in my input method. I still get the NilClass errors though. I added my full code if you want to check it out.

Comment: i think the NilClass that you are getting is because your `input_students` doesn't return the `students` that was being stored, so can you try to add `students` just before the end statement of that function? I'm sorry i dont have ruby installed on my current machine...

Comment: I found the bug. Where i have filter = students.select! { |student| student[:cohort] == :november }.

When I remove the !, students no longer becomes NilClass for whatever reason and I am able to interpolate without any problems. So strange.

Comment: ah ok, i couldn't see the filter was inside the function because of the shallow indentation, but having ! is destructive, meaning the students array will be modified to keep all its data where cohort == :november. That becomes a problem when the user input anything != november for the cohort, because the select! filter will result nil. You can read about destructive operation vs non-destructive here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#select-method

Answer (score 0):

You should use `student` instead of `students` as the block parameter.  You can check if the student object is `nil`.

```
def print_with_index(students)

  students.each_with_index do |student, index|
    if !student.nil?
      index_plus_one = index + 1  
      puts "#{index_plus_one}. #{student[:name]} (#{student[:cohort]}  cohort)"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If the object is nil (a single hash) but I still want it to interpolate onto my string template. Am I able to do that? And thanks for the suggestion I will change the block parameter.

Comment: When possible, try using less jargon.  For example, it is difficult to understand what you mean by "If the object is `nil` (a single hash)".  If an object is `nil` then it is just that.  It is not a hash.

Comment: ...But anyways, if a variable is nil, then you can still print the string `"#{nil}"`.